# Interactive console in Eclipse PDT and xDebug

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I noticed that I have an interactive console in PHP debug perspective in Eclipse near to breakpoints, variables and expressions view.
Could it be used by xDebug or Zend debugger or it is only for Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interactive Console view is derived from DLTK and PDT doesn't use it, there is no function.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do interactive debugging with **[PsySH](http://psysh.org/)**.

I hope this will get integrated with Eclipse, it would be perfect.